# How to notify Team Members via the Slack OpsGenie Integration?

Tags: slack, slack-api, opsgenie

I'm using the Slack Integration for OpsGenie to have alerts be posted to Slack channels.

However, I would like to use OpsGenie Escalation/Rotation together with the Slack Integration so that members in the rotation get notified via slack direct messages.

Right now, alerts are just sent to a slack channel but it doesn't notify members in the rotation.

Is it possible to do this? In other words, can I notify in-rotation users **via Slack direct messages**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to Slack App Integration Doc it is possible to create alerts. An alert can assigned to a team, alerts will notify on call rotation, maybe that can help you:

**Using /genie Command**

https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/slack-app-integration#section-using-genie-command

**Create Alert:**

```
/genie alert [alert message] for [team1,team2,user1..]
```

**Examples:**

```
/genie alert this is alert message for john.smith@acme.com
/genie alert this is alert message for integration team, product team
/genie alert this is alert message for myTeam, john.smith@acme.com
```

See also:

https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/slack-app-integration

https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/slack-app-integration#section-chat-user-mapping

https://docs.opsgenie.com/docs/slack-app-integration#section-using-genie-command

Answer (score 0):

[This Atlassian Community post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Opsgenie-questions/How-to-send-Slack-Direct-Messages-as-Notifications/qaq-p/1244835) says it's not possible, the OpsGenie Slack integration can only post to a channel.